# initialize map with static member variable

Tags: c++, static

I do not understand why I cannot use a public const static member of a class in the initializer list of a map (probably any container). As I understand it "MyClass::A" is an rvalue, it seems like it should be the exact same as the case where I am using "THING" which is also a static const just outside of a class.

Here is the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MyClass::A", referenced from:
      _main in map-380caf.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

static const int THING = 1;

class MyClass {
public:
    static const int A = 1;
};

int
main()
{
    int a;
    typedef std::map<int, std::string> MyMap;

    // compiles and works fine
    a = MyClass::A;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    // compiles and works fine
    MyMap other_map = { {THING, "foo"} };
    std::cout << other_map.size() << std::endl;

    // Does not compile
    MyMap my_map = { {MyClass::A, "foo"} };
    std::cout << my_map.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Using clang on OS X:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

compiler flags:

```
clang++ map.cc -std=c++1y
```

Comment: Should work.  See:  http://ideone.com/TuNTeV  What compiler are you using?  Passing the `--std=c++11` flag?

Comment: I did not know about ideone.com, I should really think about using the online ide's to double check odd cases like this. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something in the map code probably tried to take the address of a reference to your int.

The class definition here:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static const int A = 1;
};
```

does not actually create any memory for `A`. In order to do that you have to do in the header file:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static const int A;
};
```

and in a CPP file:

```
const int MyClass::A = 1;
```

Or I guess with the newest C++ versions you can leave the `= 1` in the header and just declare the storage in the CPP file with:

```
const int MyClass::A;
```

Comment: That does work, at the same time this now feels like a bug (in clang) the map initializer shouldn't be trying to take a reference here, maybe an rvalue reference but I am still a bit ignorant on those.